# Meteor settings file error

Tags: meteor

I would like use settings.json for create the first user when i start my APP for the first time, but i've error on my browser.

My settings.json :

```
{
    "admin": {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password"
    },
    "smtp": "smtp://example@example.com"
}
```

My /lib/userAccount.js :

```
let username = Meteor.settings.admin.username;

Accounts.createUser({
    username: username,
    password: 'steph0407'
});
```

And error return on browser :

> Erreur : TypeError: Meteor.settings.admin is undefined

Do you have any idea why i've this error ?

Thak you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start meteor app with: `meteor --settings ./path/to/settings.json`

Remember also that anything in Your settings not under a key called "public" is only made available to the server.
If you put something under a key called "public", it will be available to  client and the server.

You should move `userAccount.js` to `server` folder or check `if (Meteor.isServer) {}` in Your `lib` folder.